# Number of points on the elliptic curve $\ y^2 = x^3 + 1$

Tags: proof-writing

Consider the elliptic curve defined by $\ y^2 = x^3 + 1\ $ over $\ \mathbb{Z}_p,\ $ where $\ p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}\ $ is prime. Prove that the number of points on the curve is exactly $\ p + 1.\ $

**Hint:** for $\ y \in \mathbb{Z}_p,\ $ prove that there is exactly one $\ x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\ $ satisfying the equation.

Prove without showing that $\ x \mapsto x^3\ $ is a bijection

Comment: trying to prove without showing that x maps to x^3 is a bijection

Comment: You *must* use the fact that $x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijection in that of another form, this is the essence of the problem.

Comment: Why not use the bijection?  Will some evil being open his eyes, catch you and kill you?  (From a video game where he did that if you did not time your jumps properly.)